# Can't echo an array

Tags: php, arrays, echo

I have problem echo'ing an array.

```
$test = 'one two three four';
$arr = explode(' ', $test);

echo '<br />+'.$arr[0].' +(>'.$arr[1].' <'.$arr[2].'';
```

It stops echoing at $arr[1], and I need this for a special query in mysql.

What I need to achieve is:

```
('+one +(>two <three)
```

Also, I would like to know how can I use "<" character from $arr[2] to ~. So in short, what I'm tring to achieve is:

```
('+one +(>two <three <four ... <infinite)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't stop echoing, the browser just mistakes the `<` character for the start of a tag and acts accordingly.

If you want to *display* this output, you should call [`htmlspecialchars`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) on it first. Otherwise (e.g. for the query) no special treatment is needed.

For your last question: you 'd do something like

```
$test = 'one two three four five'; 
$arr = explode(' ', $test); 

$out = '+'.$arr[0].' +(>'.$arr[1].' <'.implode(' <', array_slice($arr, 2)).')';
echo htmlspecialchars($out); // only for echoing!
```

Comment: Thank you Jon. You just fixed my problem, also thanks for the array_slice tip, I never used, just learned something new. I accepted your answer. Again, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Raw output of your code:

`<br />+one +(>two <three`

Browser think that `<three` is tag. Use html special chars.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `<` and `>` with `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$test = 'one two three four five six ...';
$arr = explode(' ', $test);
$total = count($arr);

if ($total < 3) {
    echo 'Less than three elements found.';
    exit;
}

$tmp = '(+' . $arr[0] . ' +(>' $arr[1];

for ($i = 2; $i < $total; ++$i) {
    $tmp .= ' <' . $arr[$i];
}

$tmp .= ')';

echo $tmp;
```

This is one way to do it.  There are many other ways.